# How to remove duplicating rows from union statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

OK - I have looked and looked and found a lot of examples but nothing quite meeting my need.  Maybe I used the wrong words to search with, but I could use your help.  I will provide as much detail as I can.

I need to produce a report that merges fields from two tables, or rather a view and a table, into one table for a report.  Here is the statement I am using:

```
SELECT A.ConfInt, A.Conference, 
        NULL as Ordered,
        NULL as Approved,
        NULL as PickedUp,
        SUM(dbo.Case_Visit_Payments.Qty) AS Qty
FROM         dbo.Conferences as A INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Case_Table ON A.ConfInt = dbo.Case_Table.Conference_ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Case_Visit_Payments ON dbo.Case_Table.Case_ID = dbo.Case_Visit_Payments.Case_ID
WHERE     (dbo.Case_Visit_Payments.Item_ID = 15 AND A.ProjectCool = 1)
GROUP BY A.Conference, A.ConfInt
UNION
SELECT  B.ConfInt, 
        B.Conference, 
        SUM(dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.NumberOfFansRequested) AS Ordered, 
        SUM(dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.Qty_Fans_Approved) AS Approved, 
        SUM(dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.Qty_Fans_PickedUp) AS PickedUp, 
        NULL AS Qty
FROM         dbo.Conferences as B LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Cool_Fan_Order ON B.ConfInt = dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.Conference_ID
where B.ProjectCool = 1
GROUP BY B.Conference, B.ConfInt
```

And here are the results:

```
4   Our Lady        NULL    NULL    NULL    11
4   Our Lady        40      40      40      NULL
7   Holy Rosary     20      20      20      NULL
11  Little Flower   NULL    NULL    NULL    21
11  Little Flower   5       5       20      NULL
19  Perpetual Help  NULL    NULL    NULL    2
19  Perpetual Help  20      20      20      NULL
```

What I would strongly prefer is to not have the duplicating rows, such as:

```
4   Our Lady        40      40      40      11
7   Holy Rosary     20      20      20      NULL
11  Little Flower   5       5       20      21
19  Perpetual Help  20      20      20      2
```

I hope this question was clear enough.  Any Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  And I do mark as answered. :)

Gregory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick answer is to wrap your query inside another one,

```
SELECT ConfInt
     , Conference
     , SUM(Ordered) AS Ordered
     , SUM(Approved) As Approved
     , SUM(PickedUp) AS PickedUp
     , SUM(Qty) AS Qty
  FROM (

       <your UNION query here>  

      )
 GROUP BY ConfInt, Conference
```

---

This is not the only way to achieve the result set, but its the quickest fix to meet the specified requirements.

As an alternative, I believe these queries will return equivalent results:

We could use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list to get Qty:

```
;WITH q AS
      ( SELECT B.ConfInt
             , B.Conference
             , SUM(o.NumberOfFansRequested) AS Ordered
             , SUM(o.Qty_Fans_Approved) AS Approved
             , SUM(o.Qty_Fans_PickedUp) AS PickedUp
          FROM dbo.Conferences as B
          LEFT
          JOIN dbo.Cool_Fan_Order o ON o.Conference_ID = B.ConfInt
         WHERE B.ProjectCool = 1
         GROUP BY B.ConfInt, B.Conference
      )
 SELECT q.ConfInt
      , q.Conference
      , q.Ordered
      , q.Approved
      , q.PickedUp
      , ( SELECT SUM(v.Qty)
            FROM dbo.Case_Table t
            JOIN dbo.Case_Visit_Payments v ON v.Case_ID = t.Case_ID
           WHERE t.Conference_ID = q.ConfInt
             AND v.Item_ID = 15
        ) AS Qty
   FROM q
  ORDER BY q.ConfInt, q.Conference
```

---

Or, we could use LEFT JOIN operation on the two queries, rather than UNION.  (We know that the query referencing Cool_Fan_Order can be the LEFT side of the outer join, because we know that it returns at least as many rows as the other query.  (Basically, we know that the other query can't return values of ConfInt and Conference that aren't in the Cool_Fan_Order query.)

```
;WITH p AS 
      ( SELECT A.ConfInt
             , A.Conference
             , SUM(v.Qty) AS Qty
          FROM dbo.Conferences as A
          JOIN dbo.Case_Table t ON t.Conference_ID = A.ConfInt
          JOIN dbo.Case_Visit_Payments v ON v.Case_ID = t.Case_ID
         WHERE A.ProjectCool = 1
           AND v.Item_ID = 15
         GROUP BY A.ConfInt, A.Conference
      )
    , q AS
      ( SELECT B.ConfInt
             , B.Conference
             , SUM(o.NumberOfFansRequested) AS Ordered
             , SUM(o.Qty_Fans_Approved) AS Approved
             , SUM(o.Qty_Fans_PickedUp) AS PickedUp
          FROM dbo.Conferences as B
          LEFT
          JOIN dbo.Cool_Fan_Order o ON B.ConfInt = o.Conference_ID
         WHERE B.ProjectCool = 1
         GROUP BY B.ConfInt, B.Conference
      )
 SELECT q.ConfInt
      , q.Conference
      , q.Ordered
      , q.Approved
      , q.PickedUp
      , p.Qty
   FROM q
   LEFT
   JOIN p ON p.ConfInt = q.ConfInt AND p.Conference = q.Conference
  ORDER BY q.ConfInt, q.Conference
```

The choice between those three (they all return an equivalent resultset under all conditons), boils down to readability and maintainability, and performance. On large enough rowsets, there may be some observable performance differences between the three statements.

Comment: The Correlated Sub-query did the trick.  It worked perfectly.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: BTW:  The Common Table Expression isn't required for statement with the correlated subquery in the SELECT list; the CTE could just as easily be replaced with an inline view (in the FROM clause), which is what we would need to do if this were MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

you could use your actual query as  a subQuery, use an aggregate function (MAX OR SUM) on your non-duplicated values and group by the non aggregated columns

```
SELECT ConfInt, Conference, MAX(Ordered), MAX(Approved), MAX(PickedUp), MAX(Qty)
FROM (<your actualQuery>)
GROUP BY ConfInt, Conference.
```

Comment: This worked after I did a bit of editing.  I had to define your select as a table to make it go.

SELECT x.ConfInt, x.Conference, MAX(x.Ordered) as Ordered, MAX(x.Approved) as Approved, MAX(x.PickedUp) as PickedUp, MAX(x.Qty) as Qty
FROM (<your actualQuery>) x
GROUP BY x.Conference, x.ConfInt

Answer (score 0):

I'd just put the join to Cool_Fan_Order in the first select and remove the union.

Does this return the same results?

```
 select
        A.ConfInt,
        A.Conference,
        sum(dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.NumberOfFansRequested) as Ordered,
        sum(dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.Qty_Fans_Approved) as Approved,
        sum(dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.Qty_Fans_PickedUp) as PickedUp,
        sum(sub.Qty) as Qty
    from
        dbo.Conferences as A
        left outer join 
        (
            select
                c.ConfInt,
                cvp.Qty
            from dbo.Conferences c
                inner join dbo.Case_Table ct
                    on a.confInt=ct.Conference_ID
                inner join dbo.Case_Visit_Payments cvp
                    on ct.Case_ID=cvp.Case_ID
            where cvp.Item_ID=15
        ) sub
            on a.ConfInt=sub.ConfInt
        left outer join dbo.Cool_Fan_Order
            on A.ConfInt = dbo.Cool_Fan_Order.Conference_ID
    where
        (
         A.ProjectCool = 1
        )
    group by
        A.Conference,
        A.ConfInt
```

Comment: This does not return the same results.  It filters down to only the records found for Case_Visit_Payments.

Comment: Yeah, I was too lazy.  What you should do is move the logic for the case stuff to a subquery.  This should work in theory.

Comment: "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is."  -- Yogi Berra